# Sumif in AWS QuickSight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

What is the alternative for sumif (Excel formala) in AWS' QuickSight?

I need a column, that will horizontally scan the first column and show sum for the identical categories.

Please see example:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a table that is literally like the "What I need" example, or is that example's purpose only to illustrate the calculation? If it is only to illustrate the calculation, can you provide some kind of mockup of what you hope to visualize in QuickSight?

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `SumOver()`.  like `SumOver(sum({Sales}),[{Category}])`